# Format strings FutureWarning for heatmap

Tags: python, format, heatmap

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Item': [19, 92],
        '16': [None, 1],
        '56': [1, None],
        '70': [1, None]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Item')
```

that I use to get a heatmap plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="Reds", annot=True, cbar=False, linewidth=1, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

This works, but few days ago I have updated my environment and now I get the following message:

> FutureWarning: Format strings passed to MaskedConstant are ignored,
> but in future may error or produce different behavior
> annotation =
> ("{:" + self.fmt + "}").format(val)

I tried to explicitly pass the format parameter
fmt='.2g'
and I even tried to define a mask

```
mask = df.isnull()
```

to get rid of the None values, thus by using the line:

```
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="Reds", mask=mask, annot=True, fmt='.2g', cbar=False, linewidth=1, ax=ax)
```

but the FutureWarning message is not being removed.

Comment: Do `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` and see if it solves the issue

Comment: The issue I have reported appeared when I upgraded to the latest version in my Anaconda environment, as of today: matplotlib v3.7.1 and matplotlib-base v3.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understood how to address this FutureWarning message, preventing any issues with the MaskedConstant class and its formatting behavior.
The trick is to use a separate set of labels for the annotation parameter, in the following way:
just create the labels by mapping the dataframe

```
labels = df.map(lambda v: v if v else '')
```

and then pass these labels into the annot= parameter:

```
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="Reds", annot=labels, cbar=False, linewidth=1)
```

Hope this can be usefull to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've encountered a FutureWarning related to format strings passed to MaskedConstant. This warning is likely due to changes in the Matplotlib library. To address this warning and make it compatible with future versions, you can update the fmt parameter in the sns.heatmap function.

Try using fmt='g' instead of fmt='.2g':

```
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="Reds", mask=mask, annot=True, fmt='g', cbar=False, linewidth=1, ax=ax)
```

Comment: No, this does not solve the issue